# Как сделать проверку на админа беседы?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, api, вконтакте

Как сделать проверку на администратора беседы?
Я хочу сделать проверку на администратора беседы. То есть: что бы действие выполнилось, пользователь должен быть администратором беседы

```
if 'хкик' in event.text.lower():
            nkick_id = event.text[5:]
            nkd = nkick_id.split('|')[0]
            kick_id = re.findall(r'id(.*)', nkd)[0]     
            vk.messages.removeChatUser(user_id=kick_id,chat_id=event.chat_id)
            vk.messages.send(chat_id=event.chat_id, message=kicked, random_id=0, reply_to=event.message_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AdminList = []
ConversationItems = vk.method("messages.getConversationMembers", {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id, "group_id": "ID группы"})["items"]
for Member in ConversationItems:
    try:
        if Member["is_admin"]:
            AdminList.append(Member["member_id"])
    except Exception as E:
        print("Err: " + str(E))
```

Код работает на принципе исключения. 
Т.е. для каждого Member он берёт "is_admin" для условия. И если не было такого атрибута, то возникала ошибка. Изучив JSON ответы было видно, что только админы имеют "is_admin" и только со значением "True". 

А далее ты просто пишешь условие для того, чтобы узнать, админ ли это:

```
if user_id in AdminList:
    #Твой код.
```

---

Не по теме: Я не знаю, встречался ли такой вопрос, ибо я сам искал решение и не нашёл ответа. Но чуть позже сам сделал ответ.